# Adding one extra column in a python file depending on the value of another column

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a file say `temp.rule` which has say `m` rows and `n` columns where each row looks like `att1,att2,att3,...attN,class,fitness`. Suppose my file looks something like below:

```
A,B,C,1,0.67
D,E,F,1,0.84
P,Q,R,2,0.77
S,T,U,2,0.51
G,H,I,1,0.45
J,K,L,1,0.82
M,N,O,2,0.28
V,W,X,2,0.41
Y,Z,A,2,0.51
```

Where for the 1st row, A,B,C are the attributes and 1 is the class and 0.67 is the fitness. Now I want to sort the rows according to the fitness within each class and want to assign rank. So after this my file will look something like:

```
P,Q,R,2,0.77,5
S,T,U,2,0.51,3.5
Y,Z,A,2,0.51,3.5
V,W,X,2,0.41,2
M,N,O,2,0.28,1
D,E,F,1,0.84,4
J,K,L,1,0.82,3
A,B,C,1,0.67,2
G,H,I,1,0.45,1
```

With in class 2 as there are 5 rows so they are sorted according to fitness and rank is assigned from 1 to 5 and same goes for class 1 i.e as there are 4 rows so they are sorted according to fitness and rank is assigned from 1 to 4. I have done the sorting part but unable to assign the rank like this. I have also created the dictionary to keep a count of how many class 1 and class 2 and so on. And the 3.5 is there because in case of a tie I want to take the average of the consecutive ranks.

Below I am giving my try:

```
rule_file_name = 'temp.rule'
rule_fp = open(rule_file_name)

rule_fit_val = []
for line in rule_fp.readlines():
    rule_fit_val.append(line.replace("\n","").split(","))
            
def convert_fitness_to_float(lst):            
    return lst[:-1] + [float(lst[-1])]
rule_fit_val =[convert_fitness_to_float(i) for i in rule_fit_val]
rule_fit_val = sorted(rule_fit_val, key=lambda x: x[-2:], reverse=True)


item_list = []
for i in rule_fit_val:
    i = list(map(str, i))
    s = ','.join(i).replace("\n","")
    item_list.append(s)
print(*item_list,sep='\n')

with open("check_sorted_fitness.rule", "w") as outfile:
    outfile.write("\n".join(item_list))
 
list1=[]   
for i in rule_fit_val:
    list1.append(i[-2])

freq = {}
for items in list1:
    freq[items] = list1.count(items)
my_dict_new = {k:v for k,v in freq.items()}

print(my_dict_new)
```

Please help me out saying how I can assign rank like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

consider using pandas module, then you can get something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('temp.rule', names=['att1','att2','att3','class','fitness'])
#-----------------^^^^^^^^^ your file ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ column headers
>>> df
'''
  att1 att2 att3  class  fitness
0    A    B    C      1     0.67
1    D    E    F      1     0.84
2    P    Q    R      2     0.77
3    S    T    U      2     0.51
4    G    H    I      1     0.45
5    J    K    L      1     0.82
6    M    N    O      2     0.28
7    V    W    X      2     0.41
8    Y    Z    A      2     0.51
'''
out = (df.assign(rank=df.groupby('class')['fitness'].
                 transform(lambda x: x.rank())).
       sort_values(['class','fitness'], ascending=False))

>>> out
'''
  att1 att2 att3  class  fitness  rank
2    P    Q    R      2     0.77   5.0
3    S    T    U      2     0.51   3.5
8    Y    Z    A      2     0.51   3.5
7    V    W    X      2     0.41   2.0
6    M    N    O      2     0.28   1.0
1    D    E    F      1     0.84   4.0
5    J    K    L      1     0.82   3.0
0    A    B    C      1     0.67   2.0
4    G    H    I      1     0.45   1.0
'''
out.to_csv('out.rule', header=False, index=False)
#-----------^^^^^^^^ new file
>>> out.rule
'''
P,Q,R,2,0.77,5.0
S,T,U,2,0.51,3.5
Y,Z,A,2,0.51,3.5
V,W,X,2,0.41,2.0
M,N,O,2,0.28,1.0
D,E,F,1,0.84,4.0
J,K,L,1,0.82,3.0
A,B,C,1,0.67,2.0
G,H,I,1,0.45,1.0
```

**UPD**

now it does not matter how many columns are in your file if two last columns supposed to be 'class' and 'fitness' respectively:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('temp.rule', header=None)
df = df.rename(columns={df.columns[-1]:'fitness',df.columns[-2]:'class'})
out = (df.assign(rank=df.groupby('class')['fitness'].
                 transform(lambda x: x.rank())).
       sort_values(['class','fitness'],ascending=False))
out.to_csv('out.rule',header=False,index=False)
```

Comment: This seems to be working perfectly fine. Thanks. Can you tell me what if there is different number of attributes for different rule files. For an example if I want to take the rule file as command line argument and suppose the `temp1.rule` file has 10 attributes. Then how can I modify this code? I just want that the number of attributes should be a dynamic thing, not a static one. Thanks again.

Comment: @Dev, well, you can assign column names to a variable (as a list of strings), and then pass it to the `names` attribute in `pd.read_csv()` method

Comment: Can you give me one example please! As I am new to python and pandas so it will be a big help for me if you can edit the above code and add this part.

Comment: what I was thinking was I can count how many rows are there in my `.rules` file and if say the count is = `N` then the number of classes will be = `N-2`, in this logic.